# io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg could not be instantiated

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng, allure

every time i run the tests in my code i get this message

```
org.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg 
could not be instantiated.
```

I have maven with testNG and  I update the most recent  versions of both allure and testng.

> 1.8.10
>
> ```
>            <build>
>                 <plugins>
>                     <plugin>
>
>
>               <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId>
>                         <artifactId> maven-surefire-plugin </artifactId>
>                         <version>2.20</version>
>
>          <configuration>
>                             <suiteXmlFiles>
>                                 <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
>                             </suiteXmlFiles>
>                             <argLine>
>                                 -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
>                             </argLine>
>                             <groups/>
>
>                         </configuration>
>                     <dependencies>
>                         <dependency>
>                             <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
>                             <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
>                             <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
>                         </dependency>
>                     </dependencies>
>                 </plugin>
>                 <plugin>
>                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>                     <version>3.6.2</version>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <source>1.8</source>
>                         <target>1.8</target>
>                         <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </plugin>
>             </plugins>
>         </build>
>
>  <dependencies>
>
>           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
>             <artifactId>json</artifactId>
>             <version>20080701</version>
>         </dependency>
>
>   <dependency> /* testng */
>             <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
>             <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
>             <version>6.13.1</version>
>          </dependency>
>
>  <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>             <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
>             <version>1.7.25</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>
>   <dependency> /* allure testng */
>             <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
>             <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
>             <version>2.6.0</version>
>         </dependency>
>
>         <dependency> 
>             <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
>             <version>2.3.1</version>
>         </dependency>
>
>
>     </dependencies>  
> </project>
> ```

I missed some dependencies?
I want to create reports with this tool and i only the installation of this tool get stuck.
I also added javax.xml.bind in advice of some programmers and still it doesn't work.
BTW, i opened a new project and the allure did work well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also have this issue. When I add \@Step tests are not working. But working fine with \@Story and \@Feature tags

Answer (score 0):

Try changing allure-testng dependency from 2.6.0 to 2.7.0